# Store a memory address in RISC-V

Tags: assembly, riscv

```
.data
    test: .string "Hello"
    test1: .string "Guys"

.text
    la s0,test
    la s1,test1
    addi t0,s0,2
    sw t0,0(s1)
```

The sw instruction doesn't write anything in the memory.

I tried to write it differently with add or sub instructions but it still didn't work. I don't understand why since the memory address is a number so it should be able to be stored in the memory. Also I tried a li load immediate with the same value and it get stored. is there any reason for this? I use Ripes. Thanks

Comment: That is mixing different data types in a unsensible way.  `la` produces an address, so the values in `s0` and `s1` are memory address values.  The `add` computes a different address, then then `sw` stores a 4 byte value (the address in `t0`) into the location referred to by `s1`.  So, that is storing a 4 byte address into a byte string, which doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: *The sw instruction doesn't write anything in the memory.* - Do you mean it crashes?  If not, then it should overwrite the first 4 bytes of `"Guys"`, perhaps with non-printable-ASCII byte values, but if you look with a debugger, the memory contents will have changed.

Comment: The store address is misaligned, but Ripes does it anyway, so that store happens and can be seen to have effect in memory at 0x10000006-0x10000009, wiping out the first 4 bytes of the string at label `test1:` with an address. (RARS will issue the misalignment exception, preventing the store.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.